# Is it "an urban scale study" or "an urban-scale study"?

Tags: hyphenation

I have been reading about the use of a hyphen, and guess this could fall under [compound modifiers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyphen#Compound_modifiers) as explained on Wikipedia, so I am inclined to use urban-scale, but I am not totally sure. Should I hyphenate here?

Comment: YAHQ - yet another hyphenation question.

Comment: If you're talking about a study of kitchen scales found in urban areas, use the unhyphenated version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most cases both are correct. However, if you thinks that there may be some ambiguity regarding if it is a study of **urban-scale** or a **scale-study** of urban kind, you may use the hyphenated version to clarify.

Comment: Answered before, but never so pithily.

Comment: Yes, pithy. But you cannot study "urban-scale", or have a study OF "urban-scale", although you can have a study that is "of urban scale", in which case you would call it an "urban-scale" study.  In short, "urban-scale" cannot be a DO.